# GUI FTP Server Recommendation

Tags: software-recommendation, ftp

Every time I try to setup an FTP server with user account, I get into troubles.
Is there some FTP server with GUI that I can set it up easily?
Is there any good and working tutorial for setting up an FTP server?

Answer (score 3):

For GUI options:
If you don't need vsftpd, you can use [gadmin-proftpd](http://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/gadmin-proftpd) from the repositories:

[image]

**gadmin-proftpd** is a fast and easy to use GTK+ administration tool for the
Proftpd standalone server.

---

If you need something more sophisticated :

Setting up a ftp server should not be a complicated experience though.

I would suggest you try to follow the server guide at https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/ftp-server.html and if you get stuck post specific questions.

and administrate it via web interface like : [webmin](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http://www.webmin.com/&rct=j&q=webmin&ei=pnFWTuOKLIm28QP6gqy-DA&usg=AFQjCNEeMfgeVVvfIdDDYO-_hs5TMNM6sQ&cad=rja).

Comment: I have negative experience with webmin. I asked my cusomers to note down some commands, and use Bash! I suggest it to you too!

Comment: I am not a fan of webmin but it serves a purpose. I suggest that he follows the server guide as opposed to using GUI tools.

Comment: i installed it with you helpful link, but i got this error: could not read chroot() list file:/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list , anyone can help